# Not able to connect with a remote Firebird database using PHP and Adodb from a Linux server

Tags: php, linux, firebird, adodb

I made some changes to the code and it looks like I can connect to the Firebird db using the Adodb library:

```
<?php
 include('includes/adodb5/adodb.inc.php');
 $DBType = 'firebird';

$DBServer = '111.222.333.444'; 
$DBUser = 'admin';
$DBPass = 'admin';
$DBName = 'TEST.FDB';

$dsn_options='?persist=0&fetchmode=2';

$dsn = "$DBType://$DBUser:$DBPass@$DBServer/$DBName$dsn_options";

$conn = NewADOConnection($dsn);

$sql="SELECT * from Table Where col_type = 'one'";

$rs=$conn->Execute($sql);

if($rs === false) {
trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->ErrorMsg(),           E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
$rows_returned = $rs->RecordCount();
}

$rs->MoveFirst();
---
?>
```

But now I get an error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function Execute() on a non-object**

I searched for the error in stackoverflow and it looks like other folks have got that error but I couldn't find any answer which could work in my case.

I'll highly appreciate if someone can show me what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Without any errors, it is pretty much impossible for us to give you any help.

Comment: Can you point me to a tutorial? I couldn't find anything comprehensive which talks about PHP, ADODB & Firebird. Thank you.

Comment: I don't do PHP myself, so I can't really help there. However this [document](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/docs-adodb.htm) shows that you need to use `PConnect` instead of `Connect`: `$conn->PConnect('localhost:c:\ibase\employee.gdb','sysdba','masterkey');` Although I don't know the library so I don't know if that is a real difference. Note that I find your use if `if(!$conn)` etc suspicious; you have an object, is this would always go to the else!